# Need Help For Foreign Key

Tags: android

```
        db.execSQL(" CREATE TABLE " + KK_AIRLINEBOOK + " (" + KEY_ID
                + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, " + KEY_SrNo + " INTEGER, " + KEY_BNAME + " TEXT , "     
                 + KEY_Bookingdate
                + " TEXT, " + KEY_Pickupaddress + " TEXT, " + KEY_City
                + " TEXT, " + KEY_AirportType + " TEXT, "+ KEY_Trip + " TEXT, " + KEY_Cabr + " TEXT , "
                + KEY_FlightDate + " TEXT, " + KEY_FlightTime + " TEXT, " + KEY_CabDate
                + " TEXT, " + KEY_PickupTime + " TEXT, " + KEY_TotalSeats
                + " INTEGER, " + KEY_Charges + " INTEGER , "
                +  "FOREIGN KEY ," + KEY_SrNo + " REFERENCES  KK_REGISTRATION , " + KEY_ID +");");
```

Log Cat:

```
05-04 20:06:36.034: E/SQLiteLog(26155): (1) near ",": syntax error
05-04 20:06:36.364: E/AndroidRuntime(26155): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
05-04 20:06:36.364: E/AndroidRuntime(26155): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.raintek.customerhome/com.raintek.customerhome.Login}: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: near ",": syntax error (code 1): , while compiling: CREATE TABLE Airline (id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, srno INTEGER, bname TEXT , bookingdate TEXT, pickupaddress TEXT, city TEXT, AirportType TEXT, trip TEXT, cab TEXT , flightdate TEXT, flighttime TEXT, cabdate TEXT, pickuptime TEXT, totalseats INTEGER, charges INTEGER , FOREIGN KEY ,srno REFERENCES  KK_REGISTRATION , id);
05-04 20:06:36.364: E/AndroidRuntime(26155):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
05-04 20:06:36.364: E/AndroidRuntime(26155): Caused by: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: near ",": syntax error (code 1): , while compiling: CREATE TABLE Airline (id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, srno INTEGER, bname TEXT , bookingdate TEXT, pickupaddress TEXT, city TEXT, AirportType TEXT, trip TEXT, cab TEXT , flightdate TEXT, flighttime TEXT, cabdate TEXT, pickuptime TEXT, totalseats INTEGER, charges INTEGER , FOREIGN KEY ,srno REFERENCES  KK_REGISTRATION , id);
```

how to use foreign key in android sqlite this is my code but it shows syntax error near "FOREIGN KEY" what is wrong in above code please help me 
Thank You

Comment: A comma is missing just before FOREIGN KEY, it is actually misplaced after, isn't that it? Actually there seem to be other syntax errors, why did you write it this messy way?

Comment: yes i changed it but still it shows same error :(

Comment: Can you create a string containing your create statement and display it using LOGCAT before performing the execSQL, that way we can see the complete statement.

Comment: +1 to offset -1 without comment

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The format for `FOREIGN KEY` is as follows:

```
FOREIGN KEY(srno) REFERENCES KK_REGISTRATION(id)
```

You have commas.